# How to convert mHTML to pdf in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension running locally. I would like it to "print-to-pdf" active page in a chrome tab programmatically and save to local drive (or upload to Google Drive).

Currently I was able to achieve only this:

- It makes a snapshot of an active page using `saveAsMHTML` using
  `chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML` API
- then downloads it using
  `chrome.downloads.download` API to my local drive.

How can I convert mHTML into pdf? Is there a javascript library? Or a command line too that I could run on my Mac?

Any solution would work, not planning to publish this extension, just for my own needs, so not concerned about security, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two "print-to-PDF" methods you can use in an extension.

#### Interactive

Use `window.print()` in the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to display a dialog where you can print to PDF.

#### Silent

Use [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) and emit a remote debugging protocol command [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF).

- There are many examples of using the API, including the [official demos](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:debugger).
- The protocol may also be used externally, see an [example for node.js](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Print-page-to-PDF).
- Official info on the protocol: [link](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).