# How can I trigger chrome's "save as pdf" function from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that saves a webpage as a pdf (either on the disk or uploaded somewhere else). Anyone have an idea how to do this?

I've played around with converting the webpage to mhtml, and using a headless chrome process to generate a pdf from that html, though this doesn't work as well as I'd like. I've also had issues with using a headless chrome process to generate a pdf from a url when the url is stateful. I'm hoping to take advantage of chrome's built in "save as pdf" function.

Comment: Same solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57904084).